# According to user agent how to change the url domain using apache

Tags: user-agent

> Sample 
>   Desktop : www.example.com Tablet : m.example.com Mobile :
>   mobile.example.com
>
> How can i can change to www to m to mobile according to user agent.
>   (in inspect using emulator for mobile and tablet)
>
> Can anyone please give me a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a filter at the backend which when the user hits a website, redirects him to the appropriate based on his user agent.

You can also do the redirect from a JavaScript perspective by parsing the user agent when the user hits the page and then issuing a redirect like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  if (navigator.userAgent == <your logic>) {
    window.location = "http://m.example.com";
  } else if (navigator.userAgent == <your logic>){
    window.location = "http://mobile.example.com";
  }
</script>
```

You can find very good user-agent parsers on the web, but please keep note that parsing user-agents is not foolproof, since a UA string can easily be spoofed.

- [JavaScript UA Parser](https://github.com/faisalman/ua-parser-js)
- [Java UA Parser](https://github.com/HaraldWalker/user-agent-utils/)

In Chrome, you can install the [User-Agent-Switcher](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/user-agent-switcher-for-g/ffhkkpnppgnfaobgihpdblnhmmbodake?hl=en) plugin to easily change it.

Comment: I should do it by apache. How can i do that